# Creating a SQLite query

Tags: sqlite

I have a SQLite database, I want to create a query that will group records if the DateTime is within 60 minutes - the hard part is the DateTime is cumulative so if we have 3 records with DateTimes 2019-12-14 15:40:00, 2019-12-14 15:56:00 and 2019-12-14 16:55:00 it would all fall in one group. Please see the hands and desired output of the query to help you understand the requirement.

Database Table "Hands"

    **ID**     **DateTime**                                     **Result**

    1      2019-12-14 15:40:00      -100

    2      2019-12-14 15:56:00      1000

    3      2019-12-14 16:55:00      -2000

    4      2012-01-12 12:00:00      400

    5      2016-10-01 21:00:00      900

    6      2016-10-01 20:55:00      1000

Desired output of query

    **StartTime**                         **Count**     **Result**

    2019-12-14 15:40:00            3     -1100

    2012-01-12 12:00:00            1     400

    2016-10-01 20:55:00            2     1900

Comment: What would be the result if there was another row: `2016-13-01 21:59:00 100`?

Comment: The difference between last date so 21:00:00 and 21:59:00 is 59 minutes so it falls in that range so it would be included. The result would change (increase by 100) 2016-13-01 20:55:00 3 2000

Comment: At least fix your dates. There is no 13th month.

Comment: I've fixed the dates, thank you for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use some window functions to indicate at which record a new group should start (because of a datetime difference with the previous that is 60 minutes or larger), and then to turn that information into a unique group number. Finally you can group by that group number and perform the aggregation functions on it:

```
with base as (
  select DateTime, Result, 
         coalesce(cast((
            julianday(DateTime) - julianday(
                lag(DateTime) over (order by DateTime)
            )
         ) * 24 >= 1 as integer), 1) as firstInGroup
  from   Hands
), step as (
  select DateTime, Result, 
         sum(firstInGroup) over (
            order by DateTime rows 
            between unbounded preceding and current row) as grp
  from base
)
select   min(DateTime) DateTime,
         count(*) Count,
         sum(Result) Result
from     step
group by grp;
```

[DB-fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=f9711464b8b08cf70e6eccddac308d7d)

Comment: Thank you. It is working as expected, I guess I have a lot of learning to do to be able to do create queries like that.